# Update C# version in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-server-2008

I'm using windows server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.
I developed a website using the latest visual studio for web development (2012)
In my server I have asp.net 4.0 and C# 2010. In my project I used asp.net 4.5 and C# 2012.
Moving my site to asp.net 4.0 was no problem. But i've got a problem with the C# compiler.
Is there a way to update the C# compiler to 2012?
Thanks in advance!

Javier

Comment: There are no 2010 or 2012 version of `C#`...

Comment: There must be differences - The latest version supports the async keyword, for example. But installing the latest version of .Net should install it.

Comment: The versions relate to the compiler version of C#
I'm getting compilation errors on the site which I don't get in my localhost.
Try to install it on a goDaddy windows server and I'm not getting such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 on the server so that the site can be compiled  against the targeted framework. I don't know if 4.5 still uses the 4.0 CLR or not, if so you will still just select .NET 4.0 in IIS, just as you would select 2.0 if using 3.5 - if there is another CLR then you will see an explicit 4.5 selection in IIS.

Comment: So you are saying my only option is to update the .NET Framework to 4.5?

Comment: If you're _using_ .NET 4.5 (and intend to keep doing so), then, inevitably, yes. I can't just fill my petrol tank up with liquid petroleum gas and expect the car to update itself to use 'more modern' fuel, I'd have to upgrade.